# Modify Request body and then proxying in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, spring-mvc, express, proxy

I am a relative newbie of Node.js. It been two days that I am trying to modify the body of a Request in Node.js and then forwarding it. For proxying I am using `http-proxy` module.

What I have to do is to intercept the password of a user inside a JSON object, encrypting it and set the new encrypted password inside the request body.

The problem is that every time I try to collect the request body I consume it (i.e. using `body-parser`). How can I accomplish this task? I know that the Request in node is seen has a stream.

For sake o completeness, I am using `express` to chain multiple operation before proxying.

**EDIT**

The fact that I have to proxy the request is not useless. It follows the code that I am trying to use.

```
function encipher(req, res, next){
    var password = req.body.password;
    var encryptionData = Crypto().saltHashPassword(password);
    req.body.password = encryptionData.passwordHash;
    req.body['salt'] = encryptionData.salt;
    next();
}

server.post("/users", bodyParser.json(), encipher, function(req, res) {
    apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: apiUserForwardingUrl});
});
```

The server (REST made by Spring MVC) give me the exception `Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: null`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The real problem is that there is an integration problem between modules `body-parser` and `http-proxy`, as stated in [this](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/40) thread.

One solution is to configure `body-parser` after `http-proxy`. If you can't change the order of the middleware (as in my case), you can **restream** the parsed body before proxying the request.

```
// restream parsed body before proxying
proxy.on('proxyReq', function(proxyReq, req, res, options) {
    if (req.body) {
        let bodyData = JSON.stringify(req.body);
        // if content-type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded -> we need to change to application/json
        proxyReq.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        proxyReq.setHeader('Content-Length', Buffer.byteLength(bodyData));
        // stream the content
        proxyReq.write(bodyData);
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives me the error `Can't set headers after they are sent.`. Cf. https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/1168 and https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/908.

Comment: Just in case it is helpful for others: For me, I was adding more info to the payload so updating the content-length was very important. I also had to include `proxyReq.end()` after `proxyReq.write()` or the request seemed to close without any indication of why.

Comment: Be careful with `if (req.body)`, since `{}` is 'truthy'. Better to check on props in body object: `if (!!req.body && Object.keys(req.body).length > 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use express chaining for this ?
In your first function just do something like this :

`req.body.password = encrypt(req.body.password); next();`

Comment: Have I to chain body-parser first? Beacuse I noticed that it consumes the request.

Comment: You have to use body-parser in your express configuration like : `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
 app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: And it does not consume the request? Will be it available to the next middleware?

Comment: bodyParser will transform every request of your server, then in every middleware you will be able to do what you want with the `req.body`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use a middleware.

`body-parser` is also just a middleware that parses the request bodies and puts it under `req.body`

You can do something like this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

function encryptPassword(req, res, next) {
    req.body.password = encrypt(req.body.password);
    // You can do anything really here and modify the req

    //call next after you are done to pass on to next function

    next();
}

app.use(encryptPassword);
```

Generally people use middlewares for authentication, role-based access control etc.....

You can use middlewares in particular routes also:

```
app.post('/password', encryptPassword, function(req, res) {
     // Here the req.body.password is the encrypted password....

     // You can do other operations related to this endpoint, like store password in database

     return res.status(201).send("Password updated!!");
});
```

Comment: Try to log your req.body before calling apiProxy, and give us this log.